# Google indexed my application with the security token. How? How to prevent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, token, google-index

I developed a web application that has a "demo page". One of the business rules is to get rid of the login/password thing to the trial users - while requiring the user to have a valid e-mail to start the trial and log all the user's actions individually.

In my mind, it was easy: let's just use a "token" in the URL as a parameter. We ask the user to enter the e-mail and then send the access link with the generated token - pretty much like an API, but instead JSON and XML, we display an HTML with JS. Same thing in my mind.

Like this:
    https://www.example.com/trial?token=abcdef123456

It was running well until I noticed that google had indexed one of our access links with a valid token. How?

For me, this is VERY strange. We have APIs that use the same functionality - passing the access token in the URL - for years. Google's and Microsoft's APIs works just like this. The only difference is that I am returning HTML instead of JSON.

We have digital certificates, HTTPS with SSL/TLS encryption. We use RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate a secure token. We only send the tokens over a secure channel (e-mail or inside our https website).

What could have happened? And what can I do to prevent it?

My guess: Google Chrome, maybe?

Comment: Try to bind your access tokens to user IPs. Web crawler is not the only one source for Google for page addresses discovery. Moreover, if you don't want your pages to be indexed, just add this information to robots.txt.

Comment: @YuryGlushkov I think that I actually can't bind the token to the user's IPs because most are dynamic. Robots.txt was the first thing that come to my mind, however, I want to know how Google find my security token. If it's done automatically, maybe it can be done manually, ignoring robots.txt.

Comment: At least they are scanning e-mails, logging chrome actions and so on. So, even if your link is not listed anywhere, but anybody opens it in Chrome, Google knows about it. Robots.txt is one only effective formal protection, on the other hand, if you want real, but not formal protection, it'll be a little bit hardier.

Answer (score 0):

Its is likely that one of your clients, whom you sent the access URL with embedded token ended up posting it to a forum/blog/page which eventually got indexed.

**Scenario**:
For eg. I got your URL via email and decided to blog about how cool your service is and list the URL to let people take a look at it. Google bots come scrape my blog page, come across your link, go visit it and then index it against all relevant keywords that are on that page. Next, when one searches for a relevant keyword pertaining to your website/business, this URL is displayed as a search result.

**Self Test**:
Try searching for that exact URL on google to reveal any page that might list it.

**Remediation**:
`robots.txt`

**Why doesn't this happen for your JSON APIs**: APIs are for machine consumption. Developers know the significance of a API key. Unless a developer is careless/stupid enough to post the API endpoint with the api key in it on a blog, its not likely this will happen.

In case of a 'demo' link, a business person might not know if he is **not** supposed to forward this link unless you state so in the email.